# Как скрыть элемент в дочерней теме в WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, css-selectors

Есть мой сайт https://transscreen.ru

При загрузке на мобилках у меня грузится дочерняя тема: themes/twentyfifteen

Хочу при загрузке темыtwentyfifteen скрыть этот виджет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В стили этой дочерней темы wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/style.css вставляю:

```
.widget block-11 {
   display: none !important;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но элемент не исчезает.  Где ошибка?

Comment: `#block-11.widget`

Comment: помогло. поставил так: https://habrastorage.org/webt/63/70/ea/6370ea845f38a325490264.png